# Setting content type in Java for file download

Tags: java, file, http, types, mime-types

In my application I like to provide file download facility. I set the file types to `response.setContentType`. How can I set the content types for almost all known file types? Is there any easy way? or I need to set it manually like i do now, which is given below.

```
if (pictureName.indexOf("jpg") > 0) {
   res.setContentType("image/jpg");
} else if (pictureName.indexOf("gif") > 0) {
   res.setContentType("image/gif");
} else if (pictureName.indexOf("pdf") > 0) {
   res.setContentType("application/pdf");
   res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + pictureName + "\"");
} else if (pictureName.indexOf("html") > 0) {
   res.setContentType("text/html");
} else if (pictureName.indexOf("zip") > 0) {
   res.setContentType("application/zip");
   res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + pictureName + "\"");
}
```

Comment: Your container (eg Tomcat) usually provides this logic eg http://www.developershome.com/wap/wapServerSetup/tutorial.asp?page=settingUpMIME - do you wish to override this?

Comment: Off-topic: That code's a bit fragile, isn't it? What if `pictureName` is is "gifford.pdf"?

Comment: ok Crowder... i've removed the please help :)...
pictureName is the file name to show on the download window.

Comment: What he is saying is that you will match the wrong case if a different extension is a substring of the file name.  Use `String.endsWith()` instead.

Comment: `gifford.pdf` would be processed fine as it erroneously compares with `> 0` not `>= 0`. `_gifford.pdf` on the other hand...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at [javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/activation/MimetypesFileTypeMap.html) (comes as part of Java6, can be downloaded for prior version). It has a method that returns the mime type for a given filename.

I've never tried using it myself, though, and it's possible you'll still need to supply it with a list of mime types. Worth a look, though.

Comment: Tested on my Mac OS X 10.5.8, Java 1.6.0_17,
    new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(filename)
produces these results:
    x.jpg  image/jpeg,
    x.jpeg image/jpeg,
    x.gif  image/gif,
    x.pdf  application/octet-stream,
    x.html text/html,
    x.zip  application/octet-stream.
[Ack, bad formatting as a comment. Should I post this as a separate answer, or someone who can edit put it in this one?]

Comment: @Kevin: I'm not sure, are you supporting my answer, or disagreeing with it? :)

Comment: Trying to provide data on how well this solution works. No opinion, really.

Answer (score 3):

To giving a working example of what @skaffman listed when using a Servlet:

```
String fileName = "c:/temp/URL.txt";
MimetypesFileTypeMap mimetypesFileTypeMap = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
response.setContentType(mimetypesFileTypeMap.getContentType(fileName));
response.getOutputStream().write(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)));
```

Answer (score 1):

`URLConnection.getFileNameMap().getContentTypeFor(string)` works for txt, pdf, avi; fails for doc, odt, mp3...

Answer (score 1):

A FileTypeDetector class was added in Java 1.7 that allows for probing a file to guess its type.

Specifically, you can use [Files.probeContentType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType-java.nio.file.Path-). Some info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/misc.html). And here's a code sample:

```
File f = new File("c:\\temp\\myFile.mp4");
resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + f.getName() + "\"");
resp.setContentType(Files.probeContentType(f.toPath()));
```

Per the docs,  [probeContentType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileTypeDetector.html#probeContentType-java.nio.file.Path-) is *highly implementation specific*
and *may simply examine the file name, it may use a file attribute, or it may examines bytes in the file*.

As skaffman answered, there's also [MimetypesFileTypeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/activation/MimetypesFileTypeMap.html), which in comparison *provides data typing of files via their file extension*.